# Managing multiple event handlers in jQuery

Tags: javascript, event-handling, jquery-validate, jquery

I have a form that I'm working on that needs to have multiple events fired when an input loses  focus, i.e. the blur event gets fired.I am having trouble managing what order the various event handlers that need to respond to this are called.

Each form input tag needs various things to happen to it on blur.

1. Various auto formatters such as making sure the names start with a capital letter or showing areas of the form according to checkboxes.
2. jQuery Validation.
3. Post validation functions such as an ajax call

So far the best method I have come up with is to rely on the event bubbling system. Therefore, making sure that all the events from point 1 are attached using jQuery.on() to an element that is deeper into the DOM than the validation rules. Jquery validation attaches event listeners to the form element.

Whist this works it has a couple of problems. It works for the 3 classes of events I have it could well become a problem when I have more.

Is there a publisher/subscriber sort of system that people use with jQuery to make this sort of this easier?

Comment: I usually only use one event on each element, and perform all of the different methods within that one event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at custom events and firing those?

For example you could create a custom "getMeMore" event after the blur code is done:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.myInputClass', function(){
    // do stuff for blur here
    $(this).trigger('getMeMore');//now trigger my event
});
$(document).on('getMeMore','.myInputClass',function(){
    //do my ajax to get me more here
});
```

EDIT: based on comment:

The document there in the selector is simply an anchor for the event for live events.  See this example http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/qM2Mv/ where I fire custom events within another event based on conditionals.  Watch the numbers (where it doubles) to see when other events fire.  I know it is construed but hopefully it would give you something to work with.  I do this in my code so that I can manage "when" events fire based on other conditions which may or may not exist at a given time one event fires.  This allows the separation of the event trigger from the event management which is the point here.  Notice where I trigger some of the custom events from different places. (checkbox value, and based on the length of the text entry)

Comment: I did think of doing it this way but thought that it was just shifting the problem. This is because you still have to fire the custom event from somewhere, here you are doing it from the document level. I wouldn't be able to fire another after that if the occasion arose. This method is relying on the bubbling of events to change the execution order.

Comment: @MattBate - see my added example